# SQL find unmatched of multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to find unmatched records from multiple fields and return the outcome to compare.

For example

T1

```
ID    Name    Surname   Status
1     Jane    Ryan      Single
2     William Smith     Single
3     Sam     Trim      Married
4     Lea     Sun       Married
5     Angel   Byre      Married
```

T2

```
ID    Name    Surname   Status
6     Jane    Ryan      Single
2     Will    Smith     Single
3     Sam     Trimy     Married
4     Lea     Sun       Single
5     Angel   Byre      Married
```

I would like to display something like:

```
T1.ID T1.Name T1.Surname T1.Status T2.ID T2.Name T2.Surname T2.Status
1     Jane    Ryan       Single    6     Jane    Ryan       Single
2     William Smith      Single    2     Will    Smith      Single
3     Sam     Trim       Married   3     Sam     Trimy      Married
4     Lea     Sun        Married   4     Lea     Sun        Single
```

The 5th record is not shown because it is exactly the same. The others are shown as there are some differences is one of the fields.

Is there a way to do this is MS-SQL

Thanks

Comment: What are "some differences" to you? How different can they be, and according to which algorithm?

Comment: Like for example, the difference between the first row in T1 & T2 is the ID. In the 2nd row the name. In the 3rd row the surname. In the 4th row the status.

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for 3 fields that are the same, and the other one can differ completely?

Comment: Well, there might be more than one field different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a join using all fields, and count how many of them match, keeping only the records where exactly three out of four fields match:

```
select     t1.*, 
           t2.*
from       t1 
inner join t2
        on (case when t1.name    = t2.name    then 1 else 0 end)
         + (case when t1.surname = t2.surname then 1 else 0 end)
         + (case when t1.id      = t2.id      then 1 else 0 end)
         + (case when t1.status  = t2.status  then 1 else 0 end) = 3
```

This query will probably not be able to benefit from indexes, so you should verify how it performs on your data.

Comment: Trincot, this is beautiful coding. Amazing!!

Comment: Glad you like it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on (t1.name = t2.name and t1.surname = t2.surname) or
        t1.id = t2.id 
where t1.id <> t2.id or t1.status <> t2.status or
      t1.name <> t2.name or t1.surname <> t2.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Column Alias names with synonyms

```
SELECT T1.ID AS [T1.ID]
    ,T1.NAME AS [T1.Name]
    ,T1.Surname AS [T1.Surname]
    ,T1.STATUS AS [T1.Status]
    ,T2.ID AS [T2.ID]
    ,T2.NAME AS [T2.Name]
    ,T2.Surname AS [T2.Surname] 
    ,T2.STATUS AS  [T2.Status]
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
    AND T1.Surname = T2.Surname
    AND T1.ID <> T2.ID
    AND T1.STATUS <> T2.STATUS
```